# Strange argument absorption, using \color

Tags: color, arguments

I just noted a strange behavior, when ending a macro with a `\color{<color>}` invocation, the net effect of which seems to absorb the subsequent space.  I realize the easy thing to do is just structure my macro to use `\textcolor` rather than `\color` (for many reasons, including, as I understand, italic correction); however, I was just wondering why and how this behavior arises.

Here I have a macro `\flag` which in its definition ends with `\color{black}`.  I invoke it as

```
\flag{<argument>} subsequent text
```

and the space before "subsequent" gets, strangely, absorbed.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\flag[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}}
\begin{document}
This is \flag{very unusual} behavior, using \verb|\color|.

\renewcommand\flag[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}{}}
This is \flag{very typical} behavior, adding an empty group to \verb|\color|.

\renewcommand\flag[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
This is \flag{very typical} behavior, using \verb|\textcolor|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I can avoid the issue by either using `\textcolor` or even by adding a blank group to the macro definition at the end, such that `\flag` definition ends in `\color{black}{}`.  Nonetheless, this behavior seems to violate the normal expectation for argument absorption.

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps the problem has nothing to do with argument absorption, as

```
This is \color{red}very unusual\color{black} behavior
```

also exhibits the identical behavior.  Thus, egreg's suggestion that `\ignorespaces` is at play makes more sense.

Thus, to David, who claims it was done with purposeful intent, the question might be, what is the purpose of that `\ignorespaces` as part of the `\color` definition?

Comment: My guess is that some `\ignorespaces` kicks in.

Comment: I did it on purpose

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps an answer explaining the purpose of it would be very useful.  As I said to egreg, I would never have guessed that `\color{black} x` would have absorbed the space.

Comment: The spec for color commands was to work as far as possible like font changes and `\rm` absorbs space..... `\ignorespaces` works at a different level so there are cases where it may do something surprising but consider `\color{red}<newline>a line of red text` would (or would not, depending on context) indent the line of text by a space....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't there in the first test releases, the change log shows that `\ignorespaces` was added 1994/04/01 which is a while ago.

Basically the intention of the design of the colour interface was to make it look as far as possible to the end user like font changes, although the internal mechanisms are completely different.

Specifically in this case I think I wanted the outcome for **3** to be as it is, not like **2**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

1
{\itshape
one two three
}

2
{\let\ignorespaces\relax\color{red}
one two three
}

3
{\color{red}
one two three
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining the rationale and pedigree, which was really the underlying intent of my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
% color.sty, line 86:
\DeclareRobustCommand\color{%
  \@ifnextchar[\@undeclaredcolor\@declaredcolor}

% color.sty, line 94:
\def\@declaredcolor#1{%
  \@ifundefined{\string\color @#1}%
    {\c@lor@error{`#1'}}%
    {\expandafter\let\expandafter\current@color
     \csname\string\color @#1\endcsname
     \set@color}%
  \ignorespaces}
```

Now it should be clear: `\ignorespaces` makes `\color{black}x` and `\color{black} x` completely equivalent. If you add a trailing `{}` in the definition, `\ignorespaces` finds `{` and ends its job.

Comment: I feel foolish for not having tried it outside of a macro.  But I never would have guessed that `\color{black} x` would have absorbed the space.

Answer (score 2):

Am I saying a foolishness suggesting to use `xspace`?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\flag[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}\xspace}
\begin{document}
This is \flag{very unusual} behavior, using \verb|\color|.

\renewcommand\flag[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}{}}
This is \flag{very typical} behavior, adding an empty group to \verb|\color|.

\renewcommand\flag[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
This is \flag{very typical} behavior, using \verb|\textcolor|.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well since David wrote both `xspace` and `color`, who am I to argue with success?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes _I_ could argue with using my code to defeat the intention of my code!

Comment: A truly Biblical standard.  From the book of @DavidCarlisle 6:3-4, 3 “But when you code for the poor, do not let your left hand know what your right hand is doing, 4 so that your coding will be in secret; and your Father who sees what is done in secret will reward you. (apologies to Matthew)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: this is pure gold!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I totally agree with Paulo!